# Kinect v1 VS Kinect v2

Tags: kinect

From a technical standpoint what are the differences between the Kinect v1 and the Kinect v2 ?

I'm interested both in the hardware equipment and the format of the data.

Answer (score 4):

Kinect 1 is a structured Light sensor, Kinect 2 is a Time of Flight camera. 
Structured Light gives you better performance on edges where a ToF camera smoothes the data due to multipath-measurements.  ToF has less problems with ambient light.

What is your use case?

Comment: Well actually, it's my first prototype, I started by using a very cheap unsyncronized stereo cameras because Ideally I would like to run it outdoor but it's getting complicated, so I thinking about using a kinect instead.

Comment: " using a very cheap unsyncronized stereo cameras" I've read that it's possible to hardware synchronize the PS3 Cameras. Maybe that's an alternative for you cameras.

Comment: Well, I need them mostly for obtaining a point could so I can practice with pcl.

Comment: In my experience, Kinect 2 works much better outside.

Comment: @FooBar well, using ROS I managed to obtain a decent could even using a 25$ stereo camera, minuoru :)

Comment: @kamek So, in case I'm planning to test my project outside, the Kinect 2 would be a better investment, right ? in your experience, what is the maximum range for depth ?

Comment: @Cesar: which camera did you use?

Comment: @FooBar http://www.minoru3d.com/ ^_^ the only "cheap" stereo camera i could find (at least it doesn't require constant calibration) then "decent" is the opinion of a noob, acutally :)

Comment: @Cesar The maximum range depends on a number of factors, including how sunny it is, and where the sun is in the sky relative to the sensor (because the sun produces infrared light). In ideal conditions, I would say 3-4 metres. In less than ideal, it's more like 1-2 metres.